# BroadcastReceiver on Marshmallow+

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

In my app I'm using Broadcast Receiver to receive packets from external device. Everything works great with older Android version. With Android 7+ I have problems - packets comes with delay (about 1 sec) , or app is loosing them. Do you know what could be the problem ? I know I should register Receiver in Activity, not manifest - I did all of this but problem still appears. On older versions app works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

try  to use priority to Intent filter like

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_XXX);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_XX);
filter.setPriority(1000);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Comment: The same :/ still delay.

Comment: can you show part of code to understand what you are doing actually. or elaborate the problem descriptively.